# Do shared preferences not get backed up until an app is in a production release even if allowBackup is set to true in the manifest?

Tags: android

I have an app released in closed alpha on the app store and uninstalling / reinstalling from the app store deletes all the shared preferences. In my manifest I have allowBackup set to true and thought this was all that is required for backup.

```
    <application ...
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Does an app have to be in a production or beta release for settings to be backed up or does the fact that they aren't being backed up in alpha mean I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: when you uninstall or reinstall you are clearing the cache of the app. its working as expected. if you want to save it, then you need a database

Comment: I might be misunderstanding autoBackup, but this post https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html seems to say that by setting autoBackup=true in the manifest, the user's shared preferences are backed up to the user's google drive and are restored when the user reinstalls.